# how to find the position of an item in a listview?

Tags: android

I delete an item in a listview so that it does not appear! I know the name of the element (like if I have a list of fruits: apple is the target) I want to delete the "apple". To do this I use the `lv.remove(position)` where lv is ListView, how do I find the position knowing only the name "Apple" and NO (xy) of the listview?

Comment: If its binded to an ArrayAdapter, simply remove the item from the `ArrayList` and then call `ad.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: no unfortunately not known directly an ArrayList :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you maybe have used adapter, if I,I should use baseadapter,put fruit in ArrayList<>,and we can  control ArrayList ,refresh your adapter.Ok,This's my view.

Comment: you're right! I was a little superficial in throwing down the code! Thank you very much!

Comment: This is exactly what Shashank suggested via comment.